# Common base class/code for UIView and UIImageView - alternative to multiple inheritance in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have some functionality that I need in all my classes which derive from either UIView or UIImageView.

More specifically, I have gesture related code that both these classes need.
Currently my implementation is:

```
UIGestureView : UIView
UIGestureImageView : UIImageView
```

and make all classes derive from these.
These classes will again contain methods that the derived class will implement.

My problem is that the gesture handling code is duplicated in `UIGestureView` and in `UIGestureImageView`.

The natural thing here (as a c++ programmer) would be to use multiple inheritance

```
UIGestureView : UIView, GestureHandler
UIGestureImageView : UIImageView, GestureHandler
```

and let `GestureHandler` perform all the generic work but as far as I have understood this is not possible.

What is the objective-c way of doing this (without too many levels of child calling parent etc.)?

**Just to stress, the problem is how to avoid implementing the same code twice, once in UIView (or its derived class) and again for UIImageView (or its derived class).**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could extend `UIView` with your gesture handling, and then every objects that inherits from `UIView` will have the methods you want.  Not quite as awesome and subclassing, but would work on the global scope.

```
@interface UIView (GestureHandling)

- (void)didMoveAFinger:(UITouch*)touchOrWhatever;
// etc., etc.

@end
```

I have had similar issues with `UIViewController` and `UITableViewController`.  I have a subclass of one that I want to share code with the subclass of the other.  Yet there is no common place to inject that code if you want a subclass.  The alternative is categories on the common superclass.

Comment: This still doesn't solve the problem with code duplication as I need the same behaviour in UIImageView.

Comment: @LK: UIImageView is a subclass of UIView.

Comment: Ok - just saw the same in the another answer. will check this out - thanks!

Comment: @LK: Chuck is right.  Any methods you add to `UIView` will be accessible on all it's subclasses, including `UIImageView` as well as dozens of other classes in the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Check out categories: http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html

Comment: As the other answer here, this allows adding code to an existing class, but does not solve the problem with code duplication, as I need the exact same code to exist in both UIView and in UIImageView

Comment: A category on UIView should solve your issue, since UIImageView inherits from UIView.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using protocols and delegation. They solve the multiple inheritance problem in objective-c.

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
//Method declarations go here
@end

@protocol MyProtocol2 <NSObject>
//Method declarations go here
@end

@interface CustomView : UIView <MyProtocol, MyProtocol2>
```

Comment: Protocols don't solve multiple inheritance, as they contain no code.  They do provide a template for common interfaces between unrelated classes, but do not let you do something like handle gesture code.  You still need to put that code somewhere.

Comment: Protocols/delegates just seem to add an additional layer for calling back - I am trying to avoid this